# Resend an envelope in the Authentication Failed status

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the REST API v2.

When a user fails the authentication the envelope status becomes "Authentication Failed".
Using the Docusign portal I can resend the envelope and the status goes back to "In Process".

How can I achieve the same using the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be able to get away with using the "Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient" API call.  See the following page from the REST API guide for more info...

[Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Info](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Modify%20or%20Correct%20and%20Resend%20Recipient%20Information.htm)

Even though you're not technically "correcting" anything, there is a parameter you can append to the URL which is

```
?resend_envelope=true
```

This will in turn resend the envelope to whomever is currently on the routing order.

Details of the call, which can be found in the above link -

URL:

*/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients*

Optional addition: resend_envelope {true or false}

HTTP Method:

*PUT*

Formats:

*XML, JSON*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ergin, it worked. The only catch is you have to provide at least one Recipient when calling this method. Otherwise you get an error. I just sent one of the recipients (the one that failed the authentication in the first place), keeping the same information.